# Update an object with notation with a parameter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my firebase i have a collection, inside there is a document, and inside there is an object :

```
object 1
key1:value
key2:value
key3:value
```

I would like to only update certain keys ***inside*** an object say 
object1 - key1 and key2.

to do that, i need notation.

the problem is that I pass a parameter to the function that save :

```
function updateit(product,target)
{

   db.collection("Stores").doc(target).update({
      product
  })
```

So here if I pass a product that contains `only key 1`, **it will override the previous.**

So, I tried to pass this object with notation  :

```
product["product"+".title"] = "xxxxx"; // a new pair in product to pass
```

and it didn't work, **it will save a new object (override) with fields like** :

```
product
  product.title=xxxxx
```

How should you do such a simple thing ?

Comment: Good to hear that you found the cause of the problem. I'm voting to close the question as a typo, since it's unlikely that someone in the same situation will find this page.

Answer (score 0):

ok obviously, this is the answer :

```
   db.collection("Stores").doc(targetStore).update(
      product // no {} around 'product', not as object!
  )
```

see the comment that explains it all.